# The Relation between Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, relations

if I have a relation between $A\times A$

if $A = \{1 , 2 , 3\} $

if $B = \{1 , 2 , 3\}$

$R = \{(1,1) , (2,2) , (3,3)\}$

can I say that the Relation $R$ is Reflexive and also a Symmetric
because I have $(a , b)$ and $(b , a)$ and also $(a , a)$.

Comment: Yes you can. This is the "equal" relation, which relates every element to itself. It is obviously symmetric and reflexive.

Comment: B=A, no reason for the existance of B since we look for a relation on A

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the reflexive property is: For every $a \in A, \space aRa$.

We see that $A = \{1,2,3 \}$, and for every variable it relates to itself given that the relation $R = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3) \}$.

Definition of antisymmetric is: whenever $a,b \in A$ are such that $aRb \text{ and } bRa$, then necessarily $a=b$. With $A \times A$, we see with our given $R$ we see that this is antisymmetric.

With the definition of symmetric: $\forall a,b \in A(aRb \iff bRa)$, we see that this is symmetric.

So this relation is reflexive, antisymmetric and symmetric.